# MySQL Varchar Data truncated for column name_last at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql-update, create-table

I'm trying to debug an issue with an update statement.  It fails in our Java app in our dev environment, but succeeds on local environments.  When run by hand, it runs properly in the local environments, but not in the dev.  The table definition is the same in both environments, except for the current value of the auto_increment.

The error is:

```
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'name_last' at row 1    0.062 sec
```

Here is the query:

```
update party set 
master_id = 0,
name_last = 'aaa',
name_first = 'bbb333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333444444', 
name_middle = 'ccc555555555555555555555555555555555555555555556666666666666', 
name_suf = null, 
business_name = null,
 business= 0, 
 alias_of_id= null,
 is_alias= 0,
 updated_user = 3,
 active = 1
 where 
 party_id = 20986
```

Here is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `party` (
  `party_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `master_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_first` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_last` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_middle` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_suf` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `business_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `is_alias` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `alias_of_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `business` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `updated_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name_pre` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`party_id`),
  KEY `IX_Party_Name` (`name_first`,`name_last`,`name_middle`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20988 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION, @@SQL_MODE;`.  Compare.

Comment: Also check for triggers.  The query does not have an obvious error, so a trigger could be throwing this.

Comment: Michael,  Thanks for this.  We have a trigger that copies from the party table to a party_history table.  The columns in the party_history table are only varchar(45), so that seems to be a source for the issue.  It is puzzling that it succeeds in the local environment, which has the same table definition issue for the history table.

Answer (score 1):

Data Truncated occurs when the field size is smaller than the data value would be inserted: for example

your field "name_last varchar(10)" then you insert a value of more than 10 characters error return data truncated.:

see this link below for more info:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_truncation

Comment: I agree.  However, as you can see by the statement, listed above, that failed, the value I'm attempting to store into the column name_last is only 3 characters long.  The column is defined as being 60 characters in size.  So, that situation does not appear to apply.